# Does adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory work for custom fonts?

Tags: ios, accessibility, ios10

iOS 10 introduced a new property on `UILabel` and others, `adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory`. When set, it automatically adjusts the label's font size to respect the user's [Dynamic Type](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/) settings.

The docs are, ah, [sparse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentsizecategoryadjusting). Can this property be made to work with custom fonts?

Answer (score 2):

This property will work fine with custom fonts.

However, with custom fonts the system will simply adjust the size of the font, not the weight/style. It does not know the different custom fonts that are available in you family and how they are names. To support this you would need a slightly more manual approach:

```
UIFontDescriptor *userFont = [UIFontDescriptor preferredFontDescriptorWithTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
float userFontSize = [userFont pointSize];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont-Style" size:userFontSize];
```

and apply that font to your label. You will also need to use this manual way, if you have a specific size/weight combo to use for different styles... The system's not psychic

Comment: How do I, for example, tell iOS that "Headline" at the `xxLarge` size should be `MyCustomFont-SemiBold`, 24pt, if that indeed is what my designer asks for?

Comment: I don't even understand how this works. You set a custom font and size, and tick "Automatically Adjusts Font" (new in Xcode 8.3b4 today) and then what? It assumes the size you gave is "normal" and adjusts a percentage up and down from there?